# javascript remove html tags and replace html entities

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript, using regex, what is the most efficient way to take HTML as an input, and return just the text it contains, without the HTML tags and with all HTML entities replaced with the actual character they represent - eg '@nbsp;' would be replaced with ' ', and '@lt;' would be replaced with '<'?

Thank you

Comment: Apologies - I meant '&nbsp' and '&lt'.

Comment: [Don't use regex for html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1175966)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use regex for that.  It sounds like you could just do:

```
function get(html) {
    var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
    el.innerHTML = html;
    return el.textContent;
}
var data = get('<strong>Test&nbsp; Hello &lt;3');
console.log(data); //Test  Hello <3
```